# FireFox invalid regex group

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

I have the following regex that works fine in [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) but it does not work in FireFox generating syntax error `Invalid Regex Group`:

```
bld = txt.split(/(?<=:)/iu,1);
```

I have tried to escape `:` using `/(?<=\:)/iu` but it gives the same error. I could not able to figure out the cause of this problem.

Comment: So, if you have `'1:2:3'`, you want to get `1:`? You may just use `s.match(/^[^:]*:/)` then. The "the cause of this problem" is simple and well-known: JS RegExp has not supported lookbehinds up to the recent versions of Chrome.

Comment: Yes, or let we say if I have `Error 5: the lorem lipsum: in...` I need to get `Error 5:`

Comment: if you want to do match, why not use match?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well your suggestion works fine using `match` but it does not work using `split`. Also, I need to understand what's the matter with my regex and split in FireFox?

Comment: @SaidbakR FF RegExp version does not support lookbehinds. I already explained. And you cannot use `split` then.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/), as of now, lookbehinds are not supported in every browser/JavaScript environment. Thus, you can't actually rely on that feature if you want to support all browsers including legacy versions.

Since you just want to match 0+ chars other than `:` and the first `:` in the string, you may use

```
s.match(/^[^:]*:/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z4Oie2/1).

JS:

```js
console.log(
 'Error 5: the lorem lipsum: in...'.match(/^[^:]*:/)[0]
);
```