# Why is react app working only chrome but not any other browser

Tags: regex, reactjs, google-chrome

My create react app applications does not run on any other browser except chrome. Here's a screenshot of the error I am getting on firefox:

[image: snapshot]

And here is the only regex in my code:

```js
let codeFormat = /^([0-9]{1,6})$/;  

if(!codeFormat.test(value)){             
    message = 'invalid verification code format'
    this.setState({err: message})             
    return message           
}
```

and here are the dependencies I have installed:

````
    "@brainhubeu/react-carousel": "^1.13.26",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^3.0.0",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/react": "^2.5.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^2.2.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "express-validator": "^6.5.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-icon": "^1.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.5",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2",
    "serve": "^11.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.4.6",
    "validator": "^13.0.0"
  },```
````

Comment: Seems like you have used a regex which is supported by Chrome but not by Firefox. You need to fix that regex. Maybe you used a [lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49816707/2873538).

Comment: Do you have any error message or just a blank screen? We will need more info to answer accurately.

Comment: Agree with @AjeetShah -- I guess there's a regex in your code somewhere, could you find it and post it?

Comment: In the entire codebase, I have only one regex I used to validate a user's input. Even when I commented out the regex code, it still did not work

Comment: @YacineMahdid, the screenshot I posted above is all the error I got ...and it is very tiring/frustrating

Comment: Are you using [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs)? It seems to be expressjs middleware. How are you using it at frontend?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Regex that isn't supported in other browser than the latest version of Chrome. It is most likely a [lookbehind regex](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

### What to do

First thing I would do if I were you is check if you are using some Regex anywhere and double check that they are supported by the browser you want to target. Check over [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/). You should then post this Regex along with your question if you don't fully understand the operator so that other user can help you out.

If the Regex that you are using turns out fine, double check if you have any library that is doing some sort of form validation for you. This library may be using a Regex that is not supported by your targeted browser.

Comment: Here's the regex:  `let codeFormat = /^([0-9]{1,6})$/;
          if(!codeFormat.test(value)){
            message = 'invalid verification code format'
            this.setState({err: message})
            return message
          }`

Comment: Also, even when I did not have this regex, the app was still not working on any other browser except chrome

Comment: Did you install any packages and if yes could you list them in your questions with their version?

Comment: Yes, I have some packages installed.

Comment: @Nzubechukwu: Then you certainly have a look behind somewhere in one of these packages.

Comment: @Nzubechukwu you have a package called `validator.js` where and how are you using that, this might be the problem.